# Ajax responseText Null in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have some simple ajax code. All I want to do is load a php page into a container but in internet explorer I get the error: 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined. Which means that internet explorer sees xmlhttp.responseText as null. It does this with any way I have tried to get the ResponseText. Heres my code:

```
 function changeSort(type, order)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    var container = document.getElementById("content");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
      container.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //Error Line
        }
      }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Scripts/tag.php?sort=ASC&&tag=All%20Games&&type="+type,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I do love jQuery, but it's really sad when we recommend a user to use a *whole* library just because we are no longer using "Javascript"!!!!

Comment: Yes, especially since jQuery does nothing to solve the actual problem stated. If `document.getElementById("content")` isn't returning the expected element, `$('#content')` isn't going to do any better...

Comment: @jcm: when was the last time you used "raw" Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined. Which means that internet explorer sees xmlhttp.responseText as null.

No, it means that Internet Explorer sees `container` as null. If you'd tried to set a `null` value on `innerHTML`, it would have been coerced to the string `'null'`.

Probably IE couldn't find any element with ID `content` in the document at the time `changeSort` was called.

```
"Scripts/tag.php?sort=ASC&&tag=All%20Games&&type="+type
```

Are you sure you mean double-ampersand?

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Yes the code is called above content and the actual javascript is above content too. Thanks for solving the issue. And I have the double && because there is no harm done right? Just saw another site using it and thought its not like it matters right?

Comment: Well, it doesn't technically comply with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format described in the HTML4 specification. The way most form-parsing libraries are coded, it will probably still be accepted by most applications (since they'd typically split the query string on `&`, leaving one zero-length parameter which would hopefully be ignored), but that's not really something you should rely on.